# Generating Sequences with Monotonically Increasing Entropy

Tags: combinatorics, metric-spaces, information-theory, coding-theory, entropy

**Context:**
Consider an ensemble $X = (x; A; P)$. Let's examine $X^N$, which represents the set of all possible strings of length $N $produced by $X$. The objective is to systematically derive sequences from this set based on their increasing information content without generating the entire set of sequences due to its potentially large size.

**Objective:**

1. Design a function $g: \mathbb{N} \rightarrow Y$, where $Y \subseteq X^N$, such that for any two integers $i$ and $j$ with $i < j$:

   - $I(g(i)) \leq I(g(j))$
   - Every sequence in $Y$ should be reachable by some integer input to $g$.
2. Formulate an inverse function $g^{-1}: Y \rightarrow \mathbb{N}$ to retrieve the index of any sequence in $Y$.

Where the information content $I(x_i)$ of a sequence $x_i$ from the ensemble $X$ is defined as:
$I(x_i) = - \sum_{a \in A} p(a) \log_2 p(a)$

With:

- $A$ as the alphabet of $X$,
- $p(a)$ as the probability of the symbol $a$ appearing in sequence $x_i$.

**Constraints:**

1. The function $g$ should ideally possess sublinear complexity with respect to the size of $X^N $for computational feasibility. This means we aim to derive sequences without having to generate or scrutinize every sequence in $X^N$.
2. The function $g^{-1}$ should be computationally efficient for lookups.

**Additional Notes:**
Recognizing that as $N$ grows, the computational challenge may increase considerably. So we are also on the lookout for potential methods offering approximate solutions efficiently for larger $N$ and precise solutions for more manageable $N$

Given these objectives and constraints, how might one develop a methodology or algorithm to create both functions $g$ and $g^{-1}$?

Comment: What exactly is $P$? Uniform? Arbitrarily specified?

Comment: Yes, uniform distribution

Comment: You have to be careful here. If the source is uniform and independent, then all strings of length $N$ are equally likely. This then means all strings have the *same entropy*. Also, is the subset $Y$ given as an input to the algorithm? This would only be interesting if $Y$ is a strict subset of $X^N$ since otherwise any one to one map works due to the fact that the entropy is constant.